# Creating mesh between edges

Tags: mesh, vertices, edges

What is the cleanest way of creating mesh between the edges of two different objects, as shown? The closest tool I can think of is the Bridge Edge Loops tool but I am not trying to connect the whole edge loop, just the edges selected. I tried extruding one side and merging vertices but this did not work.

Thanks in advance.

[image: From Above]

[image: From the Side]

Comment: Could you clarify how you're trying to connect these two meshes exactly? We don't really have enough information to know what you're asking. Do you want to smoothly join those two pipe-sections?

Comment: @Rekov Sorry for the lack of clarification but the solution given was exactly what I was looking for. With any sort of mesh created in between I would be able to add support loops to make it as smooth as I wanted, so I was just looking for how to add mesh inbetween. A flat plane between the edges would have sufficed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You say .. 'mesh between the edges of two different objects'...

Since 2.8, it's possible to put 2 objects into Edit Mode simultaneously, which is very useful for snapping, common deformation, etc. But they are still 2 objects - their meshes are separate.

Your problem is not that you're trying to connect partial loops:

[image]

.. but that you're trying to merge meshes which belong to separate objects.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> join the objects, or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> duplicate parts of their meshes, <kbd>P</kbd> temporarily separate them off into their own objects, and join those, to make the bridge within one mesh.